# Magento 2: Unable to reindex catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1

Tags: magento2, sql, migration, indexing

I've migrated from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3.

While running reindex command for `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` I'm getting the following error:

`Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
[1064] index catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1: does not support DELETE (enabled=0) [ DELETE FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 WHERE id > 0]`.

I tried some fixes but don't work. If anybody known to this issue then please suggest some solution for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Check your change logs table, check if it is massive,Truncated that table and the site was able to reindex no problem

Comment: `bin/magento indexer:reset`?

Comment: Both the above solutions doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you get any solutions?